# Chinese Characters Lost in Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, encoding

I have comprised the following functions to take a table with data and export it into an excel sheet form various internet sources.  It works great with english characters but when the table contains Chinese letters the excel document shows random chars and not the chinese.  Does this have to do with encoding in excel V. my page?  How can I fix this?

```
function exportToExcel(table, name)
{
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';//application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
    var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>';

    if(!table.nodeType)
        table = document.getElementById(table);

    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML};
    uri += toBase64(format(template, ctx));

    //window.location.href = uri;

    var dlLink = document.createElement('a');
    if (typeof dlLink.download === 'string') {
        document.body.appendChild(dlLink); // Firefox requires the link to be in the body
        dlLink.download = outputFile;
        dlLink.href = uri;
        dlLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link); // remove the link when done
    } else {
        location.replace(uri);
    }
}

function toBase64(data)
{
    if (window.btoa)
        return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)));
    else // IE
    {
        var strUni = data;
            var strUtf = strUni.replace(/[\u0080-\u07ff]/g,
            function(c) {
                var cc = c.charCodeAt(0);
                return String.fromCharCode(0xc0 | cc >> 6, 0x80 | cc & 0x3f);
            })
            .replace(/[\u0800-\uffff]/g,
            function(c) {
                var cc = c.charCodeAt(0);
                return String.fromCharCode(0xe0 | cc >> 12, 0x80 | cc >> 6 & 0x3F, 0x80 | cc & 0x3f);
            });
            return strUtf;

    }
}

function format(template, ctx)
{
    return template.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return ctx[p]; });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of `char encoding`! This may help : http://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel

Comment: I was just looking at this, how does this help though?

Comment: Ahh, I see.  How can I tell excel to open the document as UTF-8 without making the end user go into their settings?

Comment: I might be wrong but i believe the default encoding is actually based on the users installation ! :( I dont think you can assign it into the file itself.. but i might be wrong!

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-60d59c21-88b5-4006-831c-d536d42fd861 Seems i am wrong! Towards the end it tells you how to SAVE as a different encoding.. but as for the export with enc.. not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I added  to the head tag in my template string and this tells excel to open the file as UTF-8.  This retained the chineese characters in excel.